# Design the finite DFA where 5 divides 2i+3j

Tags: automata

> a) For $\sum =\{0,1\}$ , design a deterministic finite automaton $M$ accepting the language $L=\{a^ib^j:i,j\ge 1, \text{5 divides (2i+3j)}\}$

> b) Prove that ypur automaton exactly accepts the language $L,$ i.e $L=L(M)$

---

I first find $i,j$ relation .
since $5|(2i+3j) \Rightarrow j=i+5k, k\ge 0(\in \mathbb{N})$

Therefore $L=\{a^ib^j:i,j\ge 1, \text{5 divides (2i+3j)}\}=\{a^ib^{i+5k}:i\ge 1, k\ge 0(\mathbb{N})\}=\{ab,ab^6,ab^{11},a^2b^2,a^2b^7,a^2b^{12},a^3b^3a^3b^8,...\}$
But i can't design DFA .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's consider the language $L' = \{a^ib^j \mid i \ge 0, j \ge 1, \mbox{5 divides $2i+3j$}\}$ for a second. To design a DFA for $L'$ you can essentially keep a counter $x$ for $2i+3j$. This counter is stored modulo $5$.

The states of DFA will be all pairs $(x,y)$ with $x \in \{0,1,2,3,4\}$ and $y \in \{0,1\}$.  Intuitively, $y=0$ will mean that we have not read a $b$ symbol yet, while $y=1$ means that we have already read a $b$ and hence we expect all the following symbols to be $b$.

The transitions are as follows:

- $(x,0) \overset{a}{\to} ((x+2) \bmod 5, 0)$, for all $x \in \{0,1,2,3,4\}$.
- $(x,0) \overset{b}{\to} ((x+3) \bmod 5, 1)$, for all $x \in \{0,1,2,3,4\}$.
- $(x,1) \overset{b}{\to} ((x+3) \bmod 5, 1)$, for all $x \in \{0,1,2,3,4\}$.

The initial state is $(0,0)$ and the accepting state is $(0,1)$.

The only difference between $L'$ and $L$ is that words in $L$ must contain at least one $a$ symbol.

You can enforce this constraint by adding a new state $s$, making it the initial state (instead of $(0,0)$) and adding the transition $s \overset{a}{\to} (2, 0)$.